# jQuery - Autocomplete - multiple selections

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using the official jQuery autoComplete and I want to be able to match multiple strings.

Example -

My list of available Tags is - 
"NameFirst", "NameLast", "NameMiddle"

So my user starts to type "Na.." and these 3 items come up, which is correct. But once one is chosen, and they start typing "Na.." again, I'd like the user to be able to see that list again.

Is this even possible? Is there an option for it? (Similar to the stackoverflow interface for submitting questions, when asking for a relevance tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple works